# Python MySQL Update Query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a SQL Table given a users input I have the following code. The user can choose to enter in/change the below fields which are defaulted to the values in the SQL table. However when I run the code I get the following error message

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement

I have counted it many times and it seems like the %s match the passed parameters. Am I missing something?

```
user = User_name_body.get('1.0',END)
passw = Password_text.get('1.0',END)
first = First_name.get('1.0',END)
last = Last_name.get('1.0',END)
phone = Phone_number.get('1.0',END)
email = Email_address.get('1.0',END)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE t_users SET Email_address=%s, First_name=%s, Last_name=%s, Phone_Number=%s, Password=%s WHERE User_Name=%s VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
val = (email, first, last, phone, passw,user)

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: When I try to Delete the VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) the code is able to execute but the Database is not updated

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE does not take VALUES, you should change your sql query line to look like this:

```
sql = "UPDATE t_users SET Email_address=%s, First_name=%s, Last_name=%s, Phone_Number=%s, Password=%s WHERE User_Name=%s"
```

Python throws an error because you are asking for 12 parameters and only providing 6.

Comment: I deleted the VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) and the code runs but does not update the SQL table with changes. Is this because only one value may be diffrent i.e. only email changes?

Comment: Make sure that the user actually corresponds with a user in the database. Also, add `print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
` and ensure that it is actually affecting a row.

Comment: Ok for some reason when I used .get for tkinter their was one space bar char after each variable so it was not udpating after removing it the query works now thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your sql data like this:

```
sql = """ UPDATE t_users SET Email_address=%s, First_name=%s, Last_name=%s, Phone_Number=%s, Password=%s WHERE User_Name = %s """

val = (email, first, last, phone, passw, user)

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

or you can do it like this

```
sql = "UPDATE btms_users SET btms_users.user='%s', btms_users.secret='%s' , btms_users.first_name='%s', " \
                      "btms_users.second_name='%s', btms_users.email='%s', btms_users.mobile='%s' " \
                      "WHERE btms_users.id='%s'" % (user_name, user_secret, user_firstname, user_lastname,
                                                    user_email, user_phone, user_id)
    
mycursor.execute(sql)
```

and here is a full working example:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="test",
  database="test"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE items SET name = %s WHERE id = %s"
val = ("Test", 1)

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")
```

Comment: I deleted the VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) and the code runs but does not update the SQL table with changes. Is this because only one value may be diffrent i.e. only email changes?

Comment: I add a full working example for you, wich I tried by my own.

Comment: Your second example with all the values %-substituted in the SQL string has "SQL Injection Attack" written all over it. The first example is fine.

Comment: Ok for some reason when I used .get for tkinter their was one space bar char after each variable so it was not udpating after removing it the query works now thank you for your help